# Which page builder is good for theme integration?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am newbie on selling theme in marketplaces. I have template HTML any now I want to convert to WordPress theme. I am startup so I have small budget for license of plugins.

Can anyone suggest me the good page builder plugin to integrate with theme?

I saw some best selling theme had their own page builder, it is out of my ability.

Sorry bad English. Thank you.

Comment: This question is off topic, will close soon. Please make your question specific with some code.

Answer (score 0):

i would say visual composer on codecanyon. reason being it has lot of flexibility , ease of use and further more extensions.

Comment: Hi Nirpendra, as my description. I had small budget for that, The Visual Composer take extend license to much :(

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I found new plugin for my project. It is KingComposer. Seem them just release and it works similar VC

Full features Back-End Editor.
► Updates weekly
► Manager sections
► Access our developer forum on any trouble
► Access our documents
► Access our videos tutorials
► Access our articles tutorials

https://wordpress.org/plugins/kingcomposer/

So great!